# Spring data neo4j custom @QueryResult doesn't recognize enums

Tags: java, neo4j, enums, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to create a custom `@QueryResult` with multiple fields from different nodes, but it seems like the query result mechanism is unable to map enum correctly.

This is an example that I made for this scenario. I created a basic enum as:

```
public enum MyEnum{
    SOMETHING, SOMETHING_ELSE
}
```

And spring data neo4j repository method with the query:

```
    @Query("Match (people:People)-[:LIVES_IN]->(country:Country) " +
            "RETURN people.enum")
    List<WithEnumQueryResult> findPeople();
```

when I trigger it throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate pl.degath.WithEnumQueryResult using constructor pl.degath.WithEnumQueryResult(pl.degath.MyEnum) with arguments SOMETHING_ELSE
```

I was able to see through trial and error that:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@QueryResult
public class WithEnumQueryResult{
    private final MyEnum enum; //this one I would like to have, but throws error
    private final String enum; //this returns my enum as String (doesn't throw error)
    private final People people; //this one has correct enum as a property of people (doesn't throw error)
}
```

I tried also add some @Converter e.g. `@Convert(EnumStringConverter.class)` annotation in front of my enum property, but it didn't help out.

Any ideas on how can I make my QueryResult recognize enums?

*EDIT:*

As mentioned in a comment from the accepted answer, it seems like enums require no-args constructors, so I had to change my immutable object into the:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@QueryResult
public class WithEnumQueryResult{
    private MyEnum enum; //enum is visible now!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are my entity classes and repository which perfectly works fine.

```
@Data
@QueryResult
public class PersonResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private City livesAt;
    private Test test;
    private List<Person> friends;
}
public enum Test {
    A, B
}
```

Repository method

```
 @Query("MATCH (pr:Person) where ID(pr)=$id return ID(pr) as id, pr.test as test, pr.name as name, pr.age as age")
    public PersonResponse getPerson(Long id);
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": 68,
  "name": "Alex",
  "age": 24,
  "test": "A",
  
}
```

Comment: I can, but this looks like a workaround (if it recognized enum inside object, why it cannot recognize it outside?)

Comment: @degath it looks you have some values in db which are not there in the enum.
"SUPPLIER" - in DB not in you java enum. 
Or can you post  your "WithEnumQueryResult" class here.
Because i'm able to get enum values perfectly fine , by using "@QueryResult"

Comment: SUPPLIER is a correct enum value (just did the boilerplate one, but in that case it's the second one `SOMETHING_ELSE`

Comment: try these two things
1. Either You should also have empty argument constructor in  "WithEnumQueryResult"
2. change return alias name also in your query 
@Query("Match (people:People)-[:LIVES_IN]->(country:Country) " +
            "RETURN people.enum as enum")

As i told in my earlier comment, it  returns enum fields perfectly fine for me